# grunt jshint config not working

Tags: gruntjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

Having trouble setting up jshint options for grunt

Here is my gruntfile.js

```
grunt.initConfig( {
    jshint : {
        options: { 

            curly: false,
            asi: true,
            eqeqeq: false,
            maxparams: 5,
            undef: false,
            unused: false,
            eqnull: true,
            browser: true,
            devel: true,
            expr: true,
            jquery: true ,
            evil : true 
        },
        files : { 
            src : [ 
                'dev/*.js', 'dev/**/*.js' ,  
                'files-lib/*.js', 'files-lib/**/*.js' ]
        },
    },
```

still getting the errors

> 71 |            return (this.optional(element) && value=="") ||
>   re.test(value);
>                                                               ^ Use '===' to compare with ''.

Thanks for helping

Comment: This is not the complete file you use. Just try to post a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**short answer:** There's nothing else you can do in your `options` configuration to avoid this.

**longer answer:** Although you have the `eqeqeq` property set to `false` in your `options` configuration, *(which assumes instances of the double equals `==` should not throw an error)*, `jshint` in this instance I believe is correctly reporting this as an error.

The `value==""` part in the code being validated is what is throwing the error *(i.e. it's ignoring the `eqeqeq: false` option)*. This is for good reason!

The `==` operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions, which can lead to really quirky results in Javascript. For example:

```js
0 == ""     // true
false == "" // true
```

Whilst I appreciate double equals yields the correct result for many comparison scenarios, this `value==""` example is certainly a scenario whereby triple equals should be used, or if you're a double equals only person, then you could replace `value==""` with `value.length == 0`

Additional info regarding triple equals and double equals operators, and it's various quirks, can be found in the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons#answer-359509)